# While I was trying to insert an function in select command its saying that 'multi-part identifier cannot be bound

Tags: sql-server

```
/*select p.Employeeid, p.Joindate,r.EmployeeFirstname, r.Employeelastname,[dbo][JoinDateDiff]

From HumanResources.Address p

INNER Join HumanResources.Employees r

ON p.EmployeeID= r.EmployeeID */
```

Comment: In Query What is the [dbo][JoinDateDiff] ?

Comment: Try putting JoinDateDiff in an alias ex. DateFidd = [dbo].[JoinDateDiff] OR check your columns in your function if it has alias of their respective columns before them ex. b.column

Comment: missing dot ? `[dbo].[JoinDateDiff]`

Comment: Thank for your response guys, but I could not solve the issue.